# Compose-Navigation: Remove previous composable from stack before navigating

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm using `compose-navigation`(alpha09) to handle the navigation between composables

I want to remove the *Splash screen* when moving to the next destination (I don't want the *back pressed* to get back to Splash)

Following attempts did not work as expected:

```kotlin
navHostController.navigate(Route.login.id) {
    navHostController.graph.clear()
}
```

```kotlin
navHostController.navigate(Route.login.id)
navHostController.graph.clear()
```

```kotlin
val currentDest = navHostController.currentDestination
navHostController.navigate(Route.login.id)
if (currentDest != null) {
   navHostController.graph.remove(currentDest)
}
```

So how can I remove the Splash screen and then move to next?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In Jetpack Compose `1.0.0` to navigate and remove the previous Composable from the back stack You can use:

```kotlin
navController.navigate(Screens.Login.name) {
    popUpTo(Screens.Splash.name) {
        inclusive = true
    }
}
```

The above code will navigate from the `Splash` screen to `Login` and will pop everything up, including the `Splash` screen.

[Navigate to a composable - docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-to-composable)

Comment: Cool. Thank. I'll accept yours since my old self-answer is obsolete now.

Comment: Great it worked, popUpTo(0) have not worked for me

Answer (score 76):

For **v1.0.0-alpha09** (And 1.0 stable)

Using `popUpTo(0)` you can clear the stack before navigating to the next destination. So:

```kotlin
navHostController.navigate(Route.login.id) {
    // popUpTo = 0 // DEPRECATED
    popUpTo(0)
}
```

Comment: popUpto is deprecated

Comment: @Rulogarcillan But not `popUpTo(0)`

Comment: Valid solution for 1.0.0 stable

Comment: The only one that worked for me, I'm surprised that this is not mentioned anywhere in the docs

Comment: I have never succeeded in popping the back-stack. This is the only way that worked for me, thanks!

Comment: why we have to give zero, what is the purpose of that

Comment: Works fine for latest version

Comment: The solution I found that is avoiding hard-coding 0, you can use first element from navHostController.backQueue and pass its id to popUpTo:

    popUpTo(navHostController.backQueue.first().destination.id)

For more info, here is the detailed explanation  https://medium.com/@banmarkovic/jetpack-compose-clear-back-stack-popbackstack-inclusive-explained-14ee73a29df5

Comment: Don't use this. As Ban Markovic said, this can only work by accident. You should pass destination id as argument instead.

Answer (score 23):

For a consistent reusable function that does not need to be aware of the current route, use this NavOptionsBuilder extension function

```
fun NavOptionsBuilder.popUpToTop(navController: NavController) {
    popUpTo(navController.currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.route ?: return) { 
        inclusive =  true
    }
}
```

^ Similar to other answers, it popUpTo the current route, but rather than needing to name the specific current route, it instead gets it from the backstack entry.

Now you can use it like so:

```
navController.navigate(ScreenRoutes.Login.route) { popUpToTop(navController) }
```

^ That example navigates to Login, and should clear the entire backstack before it.

Comment: clean and more dynamic way to achive this. great help

Answer (score 18):

Apart from screens, back stack contains navigational graphs, and its root is always the first thing in back stack. Our NavHostController contains graph, so by popping its id, you are able to clear your back stack:

```
popUpTo(navHostController.graph.id)
```

For more info, here is the detailed explanation  https://medium.com/@banmarkovic/jetpack-compose-clear-back-stack-popbackstack-inclusive-explained-14ee73a29df5

Comment: That's the only correct answer. Pls, rate it up to make sure everybody will follow this approach.  

Other answers contain mistakes - the start destination can be removed from the back stack in the runtime. In this case `findStartDestination` returns a non-existing route that was already removed from the back stack. And that's why `popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id)` won't pop up any route.

Answer (score 8):

**For clearing all back stack**

To remove multiple composable screens from the stack use the below snippet

```
navController.navigate(ScreenRoutes.Login.route){
                    popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id){
                        inclusive = true  }}
```

**Or To keep Home in back stack**

```
navController.navigate(ScreenRoutes.SelectCourseLayout.route){
    popUpTo(ScreenRoutes.Home.route)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To clear the back-stack, you can simply create this `Extension` function and reuse it wherever applicable.

```
fun NavHostController.navigateAndClean(route: String) {
    navigate(route = route) {
        popUpTo(graph.startDestinationId) { inclusive = true }
    }
    graph.setStartDestination(route)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Jetpack Compose `v1.0.5`

```
navController.backQueue.removeIf { it.destination.route == "Splash" }
navController.popBackStack()
```

Comment: Cannot access 'backQueue': it is private in 'NavController'

Answer (score 0):

After so many try, I've found the better way to clear the back stack during the logout scenario. Most of the production app will clear the splash or sign in screen as soon as we navigate to Home screen and there would be a multiple way to land into Home screen as well.

So, we may not know the initial screen to perform the popupTo. If there is a bottom bar, then story would be too difficult as well.

Here is a magic could that work all the scenario

```
 val firstBackStackRoute = navController.backQueue.firstOrNull()?.destination?.route
 firstBackStackRoute?.let { 
        navController.popBackStack(firstBackStackRoute, true)
  }
```

Comment: Using the backQueue is not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

this solved the issue for me

```kotlin
navigator.popBackStack()
navigator.navigate(myroute){
    launchSingleTop = true
}
```

it removes the last one though