# Compose navigation, navigating to wrong screen on pressing back button

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

[image: nav graph]
Shown above is the graph of screens that I want to build.
The scenario is, that, I want to have a nested nav graph in screen B, because, B1...B4 screens have some common functionalities and common base visuals. so the navigation that I am doing is first Screen A opens then Screen B which opens up B1 by default and I navigate to B2, B3 and then I go to screen C from their I request to navigate to B4 inside of screen B. Now, when I press back button the order of screens that I am redirected to is (the last screen is B4):
`B1 -> C -> B1 -> B3 -> B2 -> B1 -> B1 -> A`
where as the required order would be:
`C -> B3 -> B2 -> B1 -> A`
Below is the demo of the issue defined:

[image: demo]

What am I doing wrong or should do, in order to get the expected order of navigation when back is pressed?
Below is the code of the above defined application written on Android compose and using the latest version of compose and navigation-compose. (apologies for the long code)

```
@Composable
fun Root() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {
            Button(onClick = { navController.navigate(Screen.SCREENA.screen) }) {
                Text(text = "A")
            }
            Button(onClick = { navController.navigate(Screen.SCREENB.screen) }) {
                Text(text = "B")
            }
            Button(onClick = { navController.navigate(Screen.SCREENC.screen) }) {
                Text(text = "C")
            }
            Button(onClick = { navController.navigate(Screen.SCREEND.screen) }) {
                Text(text = "D")
            }
        }
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            route = Route.ROOT.route,
            startDestination = Screen.SCREENA.screen
        ) {
            composable(route = Screen.SCREENA.screen) { ScreenA() }
            composable(
                route = Screen.SCREENB.screen + "?screen={screen}",
                arguments = listOf(
                    navArgument("screen") {
                        type = NavType.StringType
                        defaultValue = Screen.SCREEN1.screen
                        nullable = true
                    }
                )
            ) { ScreenB(navController) }
            composable(route = Screen.SCREENC.screen) { ScreenC(navController) }
            composable(route = Screen.SCREEND.screen) { ScreenD() }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenA() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = "Screen A", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp))
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenB(navHostController: NavHostController) {
    val nestedNavController = rememberNavController()
    val screen = navHostController.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments?.getString("screen") ?: ""

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = nestedNavController) {
        if (!screen.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            nestedNavController.navigate(screen)
        }
    }
    BackHandler {
        if (!nestedNavController.popBackStack()) {
            navHostController.popBackStack()
        }
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Text(text = "Screen B", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp))
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        ) {
            Button(onClick = { nestedNavController.navigate(Screen.SCREEN1.screen) }) {
                Text(text = "1")
            }
            Button(onClick = { nestedNavController.navigate(Screen.SCREEN2.screen) }) {
                Text(text = "2")
            }
            Button(onClick = { nestedNavController.navigate(Screen.SCREEN3.screen) }) {
                Text(text = "3")
            }
            Button(onClick = { nestedNavController.navigate(Screen.SCREEN4.screen) }) {
                Text(text = "4")
            }
        }
        NavHost(
            navController = nestedNavController,
            route = Route.SCREEN_B_ROOT.route,
            startDestination = Screen.SCREEN1.screen
        ) {
            composable(route = Screen.SCREEN1.screen) { Screen1() }
            composable(route = Screen.SCREEN2.screen) { Screen2() }
            composable(route = Screen.SCREEN3.screen) { Screen3() }
            composable(route = Screen.SCREEN4.screen) { Screen4() }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenC(navHostController: NavHostController) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {
            Button(onClick = { navHostController.navigate(Screen.SCREENB.screen + "?screen=" + Screen.SCREEN1.screen) }) {
                Text(text = "1")
            }
            Button(onClick = { navHostController.navigate(Screen.SCREENB.screen + "?screen=" + Screen.SCREEN2.screen) }) {
                Text(text = "2")
            }
            Button(onClick = { navHostController.navigate(Screen.SCREENB.screen + "?screen=" + Screen.SCREEN3.screen) }) {
                Text(text = "3")
            }
            Button(onClick = { navHostController.navigate(Screen.SCREENB.screen + "?screen=" + Screen.SCREEN4.screen) }) {
                Text(text = "4")
            }
        }
        Text(text = "Screen C", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp))
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenD() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = "Screen D", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp))
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen1() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = "Screen 1", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp))
    }
}
@Composable
fun Screen2() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = "Screen 2", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp))
    }
}
@Composable
fun Screen3() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = "Screen 3", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp))
    }
}
@Composable
fun Screen4() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = "Screen 4", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem with your current approach is that whenever you navigate to the `ScreenB`, the nested `NavHost` is initialized with the `startDestination` as `Screen.SCREEN1.screen`. As a result, the B1 Screen always is added to the nested backstack when we navigate to B Screen. I tried to depict the problem below. We need to prevent this.

```
main backstack:    A B             C B
nested backstack:      B1 B1 B2 B3     B1 B4
```

So a solution could be to clear the B1 screen from the nested back stack whenever you are just redirecting to the B1, B2, B3, B4 screens. You might try to change the code of the `ScreenB` Composable to something like this:

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = nestedNavController) {
    if (!screen.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        nestedNavController.navigate(screen) {
            popUpTo(Screen.SCREEN1.screen) {  // don't put current destination on backstack
                inclusive = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that before navigating to the actual desired sublocation, the current default start location B1 is [cleared from the back stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66845899/compose-navigation-remove-previous-composable-from-stack-before-navigating).